# How to delete a buffer when the window is closed?

Tags: vim

When I have a new temporary buffer/window and I just do `:q`, it quits the window but do not clean the buffer. When I quit Vim, it will always popup and tell me there is `No write since last change for buffer [No Name]`.

I have the option for hidden and bufhidden

```
set hidden
set bufhidden=wipe
```

It closes the window without warning, but still popup when closing the whole Vim program.

I tried to add an autocmd:

```
au BufLeave * bw
```

It works when I quit a window, but will clean the buffer when I want to just open a new window/tab (as it does not distinguish switch window and close window). I also tried `BufWinLeave` and `WinLeave`, I did not achieve what I need.

---

I came up with something like:

```
function! OnBufHidden()
  if expand("<afile>") == ""
    execute ":bw! " . expand("<abuf>")
  endif
endf


set hidden
autocmd BufHidden * call OnBufHidden()
```

It should work but it does not. The `execute` is executed because I tried with some echo inside, but not sure why `bw!` is not executed.

Comment: if this is your intention why don't you use :bd on exit instead of :q

Comment: @bkdir Because it is one more letter and against my habit. Since my habit is a set pattern, why not just make something to make life easier

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scratch buffer in a vertical scratch window with this command:

```
command! SC vnew | setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
```

Answer (score 1):

With `:set bufhidden=wipe`, the buffer's contents are lost without confirmation, but *only if it is hidden* (e.g. via `:hide`) first; `:set hidden` doesn't do this, it just enables hiding. If you use `:q` and the buffer is still visible, you'll get the confirmation.

To get what you want, also `:setlocal buftype=nofile` (as in @romainl's answer). Then, you'll never get a confirmation.

Comment: Why do you still want to use an `:autocmd`? What in `buftype=nofile` doesn't suit you?

Comment: If I really wanna bother, I would just use `q!`. Why am I even asking a question here